# JavaScript XRM library for model-driven/Dynamics Power app not populating field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I have built a custom PowerApps model-driven app which is in very wide use across our organisation which manages workflow and database administration for our contracts.

In this app, the main Form is virtually all free-text input fields plus some Choice columns. What we would now like to do is, for some fields where the user is required to enter a Colleague’s name, is lookup to the AAD User table. This is a pretty straightforward Lookup column. However, what we then want is, when the person has been ‘lookedup’ and selected in this field, is to populate another column field automatically (so not on saving the record) with the selected Colleague’s email address which is in the AAD User table. I’m hoping I can get the JS code nailed for this, which I can then reuse across other fields where similar will likely be required.

I have written this code and added it as a web resource and associated it to the Form, but the email address field is not returning anything when someone is selected in the lookup column...

```js
function populateEmailAddress() {
    var lookupField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("crc1e_peoplepickertest");
    var emailAddressField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("crc1e_ppemail");

    if (lookupField.getValue() != null) {
        var lookupValue = lookupField.getValue()[0];
        var lookupId = lookupValue.id;
        var lookupType = lookupValue.entityType;

        if (lookupType === "systemuser") {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/systemusers(" + lookupId + ")?$select=internalemailaddress", false);
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    req.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                        emailAddressField.setValue(result["internalemailaddress"]);
                    }
                    else {
                        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            req.send();
        }
    }
}

lookupField.addOnChange(populateEmailAddress);
```

I've asked around and cannot get this to work, even asking MS. I don't know if I need an event handler on the form?

Cheers
K.

Tried with the code, expecting that the email address field would be populated, but nothing happens. Does it need an event handler?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you may need to do:

1. Add `populateEmailAddress` function as an **[OnChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/configure-event-handlers-legacy)** event handler for the lookup field. Then when the lookup value gets changed, the function gets called. Remember to check the "Pass execution context as the first parameter" option when you add the event handler.
2. `Xrm.Page` is not recommended anymore, replace it with the new `formContext` object.
3. Replace `XMLHttpRequest` with existed API [`Xrm.WebApi.online`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/online).

In the final, your code should look like this:

```
function populateEmailAddress(executionContext) {
// get formContext
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var lookupField = formContext.getAttribute("crc1e_peoplepickertest");
var emailAddressField = formContext.getAttribute("crc1e_ppemail");

if (lookupField.getValue() != null) {
    var lookupValue = lookupField.getValue()[0];
    var lookupId = lookupValue.id;
    var lookupType = lookupValue.entityType;
    if (lookupType === "systemuser") {
        Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord("systemuser", lookupId, "?$select=internalemailaddress").then(
            function success(result) {
                if(result && result["internalemailaddress"]){
                    emailAddressField.setValue(result["internalemailaddress"]);
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

}